# How to convert one data type to another?

Tags: mysql

I have table tab1 (pseudo-structure)

```
tab1
{
  fname char(20)
  code int
}
```

I have a procedure like this

```
change(a varchar(20) )
{
  update tab1
  set code = a where fname = 'lisa'
}
```

I want `a` was every thing except `int`;

```
i want convert varchar to int and int to varchar too.
```

Comment: Convert `varchar(20)` to `int` or...?

Comment: yes i want convert varchar to int and int to varchar too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need it. If you invoke it `CALL change('123a31')` MySQL will do its best to get a number out of your varchar.

If you absolutely need to cast try `SELECT CAST('123' AS SIGNED)` [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)